# Popup window for a custom backend button

Tags: libraries

I have created a custom backend button (JToolbarHelper::custom()), when a user clicks the button it shows a popup window with some content. How can I do so, not using JToolbarHelper::preview() as this button will do more than just displaying the content. Is there some inbuilt library function to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Popup windows are part of core Joomla.
What you need to do to activate functionality is:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.modal','a.popuplink');
```

"a.popuplink" can be replaced by any jQuery selector.
Script used by Joomla is squeezbox.
Also 3+ versions of Joomla you can use bootstrap modals, but it will be a little bit mode complicated.

---

Full example:

anywhere in your view put

```
<a class="btn popuplink" href="http://joomla.stackexchange.com/posts/17068">Link that opens up popup styled like button</a>
<?php
JHtml::_('behavior.modal','a.popuplink');
?>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide an example too. I am new to joomla and hence a more detailed explanation would be great :)

Comment: I'd say that it's to simple for explanation, but I've tried and added the example. Really all you need is past the <?php JHtml::_('behavior.modal','a.popuplink'); ?> and all your links (<a> tags) having class "popuplink" would open in popup.

Comment: will try this and ping you again for help :) thanks

Comment: @NikitaDhiman you're welcome

Answer (score -1):

The popup windows are not part of core Joomla. You need some javascript for this, like jQuery or mootools, or a single JavaScript file with the function defined in there.

Since you can't be sure which backend template is used you have to bring your popup code with you.

So: no, there is no inbuild library function (afaik).